# Profile page for logged user - laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, post, get, routes, profile

The problem is, when i submit the form, the browser throw `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:`

**My route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::resource('dash/reports', 'Dash\\ReportsController');
});

/* ruote for Admin */
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {
    Route::resource('dash/categories', 'Dash\\CategoriesController');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {
    Route::resource('dash/roles', 'Dash\\RolesController');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {
    Route::resource('dash/permissions', 'Dash\\PermissionsController');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {
    Route::resource('dash/users', 'Dash\\UsersController');
});

/* another routes */
Route::auth();
Route::get('/profile-edit/{id}', 'Dash\\UsersController@editUser');
```

**My controller:**

```
public function editUser($id)
{
    $auth = Auth::user()->id;
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    if($auth == $user->id){
        return view('dash.users.update_profile', compact('user'));
    }
    return redirect('errors/404');
}

public function storeUpdatedUser($id, Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required', 'name' => 'required', 'password' => 'required', 'surname' => 'required', ]);

    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->save();

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'User updated!');

    return redirect('/');           
}
```

**the view:**

```
{!! Form::model($user, [
        'method' => 'PATCH',
        'url' => ['/profile-edit', $user->id],
        'class' => 'form-horizontal'
    ]) !!}
........
```

WHere is the problem? And another problem is the field "password" show me a hased password, anyone can explaine me ?

[image]

Comment: Please run `php artisan route:list` and tell me how your `edit` route looks like (URI column).

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a PATCH request to a get route:

```
Route::get('/profile-edit/{id}', 'Dash\\UsersController@editUser');

{!! Form::model($user, [
    'method' => 'PATCH',
    'url' => ['/profile-edit', $user->id],
    'class' => 'form-horizontal'
    ]) !!}
```

Change the route from get to patch

```
Route::patch('/profile-edit/{id}', 'Dash\\UsersController@editUser');
```

Comment: if i use patch() i can't see the page /profile-edit/, the page throw the same error **MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:**

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Route::put('/profile-edit/{id}'...`

Comment: same error **MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:**

Comment: And if you try `'method' => 'PUT',` with `Route::put()`?

Comment: Try also to change url to `'url' => ['/profile-edit/'.$user->id]` (don't forget to use PUT everywhere as mentioned before)

Answer (score 0):

solved:

```
Route::get('/profile-edit/{id}/edit', 'Dash\\UsersController@editUser');
Route::patch('/profile-edit/{id}', 'Dash\\UsersController@storeUpdatedUser');
```